# python beautiful soup parse string that has only closing br tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
html="""<div class="practice-location">
<strong>Primary Location of Practice</strong><br/>
                        Suite 100<br/>2010 Eglinton Avenue West<br/>TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3<br/><strong>
</div>"""
```

I have problem extracting address.

I want a string to look like

```
mystr=Suite 100,2010 Eglinton Avenue West, TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3
```

My Code:

```
   dt = soup.find(class_ ={"practice-location"})
   print dt
   ele=dt.find_all('strong')
   print ele
   add=[]
   for x in ele.find_next_siblings(text=True):
     add.append(x.text)
   location=','.join(add)
   print location
```

Comment: can you provide the code that does the request for this particular html? or is it a local html file?

Comment: sorry I forgot the 8 spaces while asking the question

Comment: I am sorry guys. This is a problem when someone switches from perl to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.extract()` to remove tag and `.replace_with` to replace tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<div class="practice-location">
<strong>Primary Location of Practice</strong><br/>
                        Suite 100<br/>2010 Eglinton Avenue West<br/>TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3<br/><strong>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
dt = soup.find(class_ ={"practice-location"})
# remove "strong" here
dt.strong.extract()
for br in dt.select('br'):
    br.replace_with(', ')
print(dt.text.strip().strip(',').strip())

# Suite 100, 2010 Eglinton Avenue West, TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3
```

about 3x `strip()`, after `<br>` replaced with the `,` it will produce string

```
, 
                    Suite 100, 2010 Eglinton Avenue West, TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3,
```

first `.strip()` remove space and new line, second remove comma, and third replace again space and newline.

Comment: if you could explain dt.text.strip().strip(',').strip() it would be immense help to all

Answer (score 0):

you could just do .text or .extract, but I was thinking you wanted them seperated with ','

this will do that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag   



def split_at_br(text):
    string = ''
    for x in text:

        if isinstance(x, str) and '\n' not in x:
            string += x

        if isinstance(x, str) and '\n' in x:
            x = x.split('\n')
            x_temp = []
            for ele in x:
                ele = ele.strip()
                x_temp.append(ele)
            x = ' '.join(x_temp)
            x = x.strip()
            string += x

        if isinstance(x, Tag):
            if x.name != 'br':
                x = x.text
                string += x
            else:
                x = ','
                string += x

    string = string[:-2].strip()
    return string
```

gives output:

```
html="""<div class="practice-location">
<strong>Primary Location of Practice</strong><br/>
                        Suite 100<br/>2010 Eglinton Avenue West<br/>TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3<br/><strong>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select('div.practice-location')
text = text[0].contents

mystr = split_at_br(text)
```

then

```
In [1]: print (mystr)
Primary Location of Practice,Suite 100,2010 Eglinton Avenue West,TorontoÂ ONÂ Â M6E 2K3
```

Comment: Thanks chitown88 . I tried your code in mine but it gave me some output as Primary Location of Practice,,,,Phone:,Fax:,Electoral District

Comment: ah ok. that just means that additional info (Phone: Fax:, etc.) are part of the html in those tags. I was under the impression they all followed the same format. So could be a little trickier to factor that as well. but not impossible

Comment: Thanks everybody . I now a new problem. In some strings I have address,phone,fax and some only have address. I wan't them in three different variables. I don't wanna use regex for this or may be only a little regex. Thanks for the help.